# Jquery datepicker dropdown shows current date not the selected date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

[image]

If you look, the selected value of start date is 'December 2016' but when I click on it it shows the current month and year. It should show the selected value(December 2016) instead.
Any idea how do I resolve it?

Below is the code of the start date datepicker:

```
$('#startDateEdEdit').datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showButtonPanel: true,
        dateFormat: 'MM yy',
        setDate: startDateEd,
        yearRange: `1920:${todayYear+10}`,
        onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
            startDateEdEdit = new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1);
            $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
            if(endDateEdEdit < startDateEdEdit){
                $('#endDateEdEdit').datepicker('setDate',null);
            }
            else {
                var duration = $('#endDateEdEdit').datepicker('getDate')?durationCalculator(startDateEdEdit, endDateEdEdit):null;
                document.getElementById('durationEdit').value = duration.duration;
                document.getElementById('eduEdit-duration').value = duration.years;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If your prefer to use Month picker then you can look at this https://kidsysco.github.io/jquery-ui-month-picker/ and jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/kidsysco/JeZap/

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue with datepicker dateformat field. What you can do is instead of `dateFormat: 'MM yy'` replace with `dateFormat: 'dd MM, yy'` Would that work?

Comment: but i dont want the user to select the day. I just want to give the user to option to select the month and year.

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak between onClose and beforeShow events.

```
$(function() {
$('.date-picker').datepicker( {
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    dateFormat: 'MM yy'
 onClose: function() {
    var iMonth = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();

    var iYear = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();

    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));

 },
 beforeShow: function() {

   if ((selDate = $(this).val()).length > 0)

   {
      iYear = selDate.substring(selDate.length - 4, selDate.length);
      iMonth = jQuery.inArray(selDate.substring(0, selDate.length - 5),
               $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));

      $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
      $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(iYear, iMonth, 1));
   }
}
});});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DBpJe/12185/)